# Marginal pdf $f_2(y)$ is proportional to $g_2(y)$.

Tags: statistics

The question in DeGroot's Probability and Statistics is:

Given the joint pdf of X and Y,
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
c\sin x, & 0\le x\le \pi/2, 0\le y\le 3\\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
determine the condition pdf of Y for every given value of X.

Looking at his solution:

Since $f(x, y) = 0$ outside a rectangle with sides parallel to the $x$ and $y$ axes and since $f(x, y)$ can be factored as $f(x,y)=g_1(x)g_2(y)$, with $g_1(x) = c\sin(x)$ and $g_2(y) = 1$, it follows that X and Y are independent random variables. Furthermore, for $0 ≤ y ≤ 3$, the marginal pdf  $f_2(y)$ must be proportional to $g_2(y)$.

Then there is a bit more to the solution, but the part I am having trouble with is the last sentence; that is, why must the marginal pdf $f_2(y)$ be proportional to $g_2(y)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $0\leq y\leq 3$ we have
$$
P(Y\leq y)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^y f(x,y)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy=\int_0^y kg_2(y)\,\mathrm dy
$$
with
$$
k=\int_0^{\pi/2}g_1(x)\,\mathrm dx
$$
showing that $Y$ has density $y\mapsto kg_2(y)\mathbf{1}_{0\leq y\leq 3}$. In particular, the marginal density of $Y$ is proportional to $g_2$ on $[0,3]$.

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks.